# kafka-connect-jdbc date time

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are looking to import data from our legacy database(on mysql) to kafka using kafka-connect-jdbc. I have been able to setup the basic examples and get it working.

One of the issues is that one of the columns which is supposed to be timestamp, has an invalid value for all the rows coz of which we get the exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

I can easily exclude that column and have the data imported using the custom query option from the kafka-connect-jdbc by writing a select query excluding that column. Just wanted to understand the implications, in terms of offset management  etc. One of the issues, as per the docs, is that this would limit me to a single topic per connector. Anything else that needs to be kept in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this particular problem(for dates) using mysql zeroDateTimeBehavior option in the connection string. Adding something like this &zeroDateTimeBehavior=round fixed it for me where by the dates no longer remained 0000-00-00.  More info here:

From the MySql docs

```
zeroDateTimeBehavior
```

> What should happen when the driver encounters DATETIME values that are
>   composed entirely of zeros (used by MySQL to represent invalid dates)?
>   Valid values are "exception", "round" and "convertToNull".
>
> Default: exception
>
> Since version: 3.1.4

I would still like to know the implications of using custom query though.